# Is there a way to make the bash auto-complete show a different completion list than what will be used to actually auto-complete?

Tags: bash, auto-completion

first question here ^^

I have a an auto-completion script which contains this :

```
    COMPREPLY=()
    mapfile -t MAP< <(compgen -A directory -- "$cur")
    for entry in "${MAP[@]}"; do
#       if [[ "$entry" =~ ([^/]*$) ]]; then
#           COMPREPLY+=("$(printf "%q" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")")
            COMPREPLY+=("$(printf "%q/" "$entry")")
#       fi
    done;;
```

The goal is to autocomplete a command with a directory name so that `mycmd m[TAB]` will be completed as `mycmd mydir/`

This works just fine, but if I have 2 directories `mydir1 mydir2` and I am in `mydir1`, then `mycmd ../m[TAB]` will display `../mydir1 ../mydir2`.

I want to be able to autocomplete to `mycmd ../mydir1` while only displaying `mydir1 mydir2` just as `ls ../` does. The commented lines allow me to change the display as wanted but autocompletes as `mycmd mydir1` which is incorrect.

Is it possible to display `mydir1 mydir2` while autocompleting as `mycmd ../mydir1` ?

Thanks !

Comment: That's the behaviour you get by `complete -d mycmd`, so if your completion is complex and changes based on the word being completed, check out the section starting "There is some support for dynamically modifying completions" in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion

Comment: It is roughly the behaviour of `complete -d mycmd` because it is able to correctly autocomplete directories with spaces, but it doesn't change much here. According to the doc, `complete -o plusdirs -D mycmd` seems to do the trick